# When I use "response.data" to print the JSON data, it only prints out whole response instead of the JSON

Tags: java, angularjs, json

I'm sending a get request from an angularjs 1.5x client to a Java HTTP method and in the client I will print the response which will contain some JSON data.

```
// method from an angular service that sends ajax requests
this.getTask = function(taskName) {
        var url = 'http://localhost:9998/tasks/' + taskName;
        var config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };

        $http.get(url, config)
            .then(function successCallback(response) {
               console.log(response.data);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
               console.log(response);
            });
    };
```

The request executes successfully but when the statement `response.data` does not return the JSON data but it instead returns this;

`Object { data: Object, status: 302, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: "Found" }`

Usually that statement would print out the data Object contained in the object above. What is going wrong?

Comment: My guess is that it is not using the successCallback but the errorCallback which prints out the response. Try adapting your code to look like `then(function(response) {console.log(response.data}).catch(function(err) {console.error(err)}); `

Answer (score -2):

```
var data = JSON.parse(apiResponse);

var name = data.response;
```